# PHP Write Posted Data to File

Tags: php, vb.net, web

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm trying to get a small script running. I have a VB .net program that posts data using the following function.

```
Public Sub PHPPost(ByVal User As String, ByVal Score As String)
    Dim postData As String = "user=" & User & "&" & "score=" & Score
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://myphpscript"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postReqStream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postReqStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postReqStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Where "myphpscript" is acutally the full URL to the PHP script. Basically I'm trying to POST the "User" variable and the "Score" variable to the PHP script. The script I've tried is as follows:

```
<?php
    $File = "scores.rtf";
    $f = fopen($File,'a');
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $score = $_POST["score"];
    fwrite($f,"\n$name $score");
    fclose($f);
?>
```

The "scores.rtf" does not change. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ahead of time, I'm new to PHP.

Comment: is there no any error about file permissions?

Comment: the PHP file does not output anything.

Answer (score 0):

> The "scores.rtf" does not change.

well **RTF files** is handled differently because its not really a pure **text file** it contains meta-data and tags that controls how text is displayed on the rtf file. please have a time to read to the following sources

http://www.webdev-tuts.com/generate-rtf-file-using-php.html

http://b-l-w.de/phprtf_en.php

http://paggard.com/projects/doc.generator/doc_generator_help.html

if in any case you want a normal text file you can use the code below, don't use `fwrite()`, please use `file_put_contents()`

```
file_put_contents("scores.txt", "\n$name $score");
```

Comment: I tried the same code with a normal text file and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your script is receiving the POST variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

You can try file_put_contents, it combines the use of fopen ,fwrite & fclose.

It could be wise to use something like isset/empty to check that there is something to write before writing.

```
<?php
$file = 'scores.rtf';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= print_r($_POST);

//Once confirmed remove the above line and use below
$current .= $_POST['name'] . ' ' . $_POST['score'] . "\n";

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Also, totally overlooked the RTF part, definitely look into what Mahan mentioned. I'd suggest the above if you have no need for that specific file type.

Comment: I used the code you put, no difference. Should I add code to VB side to read the response?

Comment: What about read/write permissions on the directory? Does the file get created? Make sure that the directory has the correct permissions and delete the file and start over.

Comment: The file doesn't get created, and the directory is the /var/www directory on a RaspberryPi running lighttpd as the server. The ouput of "ls -ld /var/www" is "drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 28 23:38 /var/www"

Comment: Looks like write permission is on the directory, possibly a PHP error. Try running the script via command line "php myphpscript.php" is there any output? Otherwise you may need to check the log directory. You may be suppressing error reporting, an adjustment can be made within php.ini to output errors to screen, search for "error_reporting". http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Sounds like something may not be configured properly within PHP.

Comment: I wrote a script that just echoes a line and it worked just fine. I'll look into the error reporting and should I add code to the VB side to read the server's response? Will that help with the debugging?

Comment: You can if you like, its another addition which is just posting variables to the script. I'd just create a HTML form that posts those values to it, it's essentially the same thing (faster to test, if you can run the form in your browser that is). But then again it comes down to your work environment and what's easiest for you.

Comment: Alright well thanks for the help. I'll try to find a way around it.